# Generalization of Łoś theorem to infinitary logic

Tags: logic, model-theory, boolean-algebra, filters

"It is straightforward to check that, essentially by the same proof as for $\mathcal{L}_{\omega \omega}$, Łos’s Theorem 0.6 holds for $ \mathcal{L}_{\kappa \kappa } $ and ultraproducts by $\kappa$-complete ultrafilters."

-Kanamori, Akihiro. The Higher Infinite: Large Cardinals in Set Theory from Their Beginnings (Springer Monographs in Mathematics) (p.37). Springer.

The proof is of course by induction on the complexity of the formula. Now, I can see why you need $\kappa$-completeness for the case of a conjunction of less-than-$\kappa$-many formulas, but do we need it for the case of a sequence of existential quantifiers of length less than $\kappa$? It seems to me that it is not needed, but I wanted to check.

Comment: Suppose you have $\exists x_0 \phi$, $\exists x_1 \exists x_0 \phi$, $\exists x_2 \exists x_1 \exists x_0 \phi$, and so on. How you take the limit?